# Please make [eventsource] a synonym of [server-sent-events]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Mainly, they both refer to the same html5 api. Although [eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventsource) could refer to another topic altogether, the tags' wikis are essentially the same, with [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) being more complete.

[server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events):

> Server-Sent Events (SSE) are a a part of the HTML5 specification. SSE
>   allows a uni-directional persistent connection between a client and
>   server, such that the client makes only a single request and the
>   server keeps pushing data to the client continuously, until the
>   connection is closed.

[eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventsource):

> SSE (Server Sent Events), also known as EventSource, is an HTML5 API
>   for pushing data from server to browser.

Comment: I'm sure there are non-HTML event-sources...

Comment: @Deduplicator Then the [tag:eventsource] wiki should be different. From the ~50 tagged questions, they all refer to HTML5 SSE, even though many are not tagged [tag:server-sent-events].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done**

I have completed cleanup of [eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventsource).

- [eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventsource) => **Ratag** to [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events)
- [etw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etw)/[etw-eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etw-eventsource) => **Retag** to [etw-eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etw-eventsource)
- [fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) => **Untag**

I also found another tag that I have finished cleaning up.

- [server-side-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-events) (x37) => **Ratag** to [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events)
- A few random questions just had the tag removed as it did not apply.

> Server-sent events is a technology for providing push notifications from a server to a browser client in the form of DOM events. The Server-Sent Events EventSource API is now being standardized as part of HTML5 by the W3C.